# Apply function to multiple pandas columns with Args

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, args, keyword-argument

I wrote the following function:

```
def unique_values(df, column):

unique = df[column].unique()
clean = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(unique)
clean.columns = [column]

return clean
```

I would like to apply the following function to various columns in a df. As something like this:

```
unique1, unique2, unique3 = unique_values(df, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
```

If I add an args in the following way:

```
 def unique_values(df, *column):

    unique = df[column].unique()
    clean = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(unique)
    clean.columns = [column]

    return clean
```

and apply the function like this:

```
 unique1, unique2, unique3 = unique_values(df, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am not trying to apply the function to the dataframe, but set the variable of the df and columns and save them as new DFs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way by iterating though `column`:

```
def unique_values(df, *column):
    to_return=[]
    for col in column:
        unique = df[col].unique()
        clean = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(unique)
        clean.columns = [col]
        to_return.append(clean)
    return to_return
# this way this works:
unique1, unique2, unique3 = unique_values(df, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a genius

Comment: How would you switch the iteration between columns and df? I changed the function to the following:

`def vlookup(col, *df):
    
    to_return = []
    for dfs in df:
        
        unique = dfs[col].unique()
        clean = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(unique)
        clean.columns = [col]        
        to_return.append(clean)

        
    return to_return`

But I get a series of lists rather than 1 dataframe with all values for that column for each dataframe

Comment: You can try returning `return pd.concat(to_return)` instead of `return to_return`

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small wrapper function that calls your `unique_values()` function with the list of columns that you pass as arguments, like so:

```py
def df_unique_values(df, *columns):
    return [unique_values(df, x) for x in columns]
```

This function returns a list containing the result of each call to `unique_values()` for a different column. Use this function like so:

```
unique1, unique2, unique3 = df_unique_values(df, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
```